# React native render list of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Let's say i have a function who appends to a list some components. The example data is:

```js
var MyComponentList = ['<Text>1</Text>','<Text>2</Text>']
```

And i just want to render every component of the list in a scrollview.
Example:

```js
  render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView>
           {The component goes here}
        </ScrollView>
    )
  }
```

How can it be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it without `''`

```
const componentList = [<Text>1</Text>, <Text>2</Text>]
```

And render it like

```
render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView>
           {componentList}
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

Another way to do it is have only the data and use `.map`

```
render() {
    const data = [1, 2]
    return (
        <ScrollView>
           {data.map(x => <Text>{x}</Text>)}
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```